# Can I overload methods in Moose?

Tags: perl, moose

I am looking for a solution similar to Java's whereby I can create methods with the same name but with different parameter lists.

e.g.

```
method makeDeposit() {
    system("cls");
    print "How much money do you want to deposit?: ";
    chomp (my $amount = <STDIN>);
    $self->insufficientFunds(0);
    $self->balance($self->balance() + $amount);
    $self->performBalanceInquiry();
    return;
}

method makeDeposit(Int $amount) {
    $self->insufficientFunds(0);
    $self->balance($self->balance() + $amount);
    $self->performBalanceInquiry();
    return;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you try it?!?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perl is a rather loosely typed language, and the (pseudo)-type names in method signatures are just a shorthand for dynamic input validation code.

However, in the infinite lands of CPAN there lives the module [`MooseX::MultiMethods`](https://metacpan.org/module/MooseX%3a%3aMultiMethods) which will allow you to do what you want—but you have to prefix your methods with the `multi` keyword.

E.g.

```
multi method makeDeposit() { ... }
multi method makeDeposit(Int $amount) { ... }
```

Comment: Aside: multimethods are strictly more powerful than overloading. If you aren’t aware of that fact, debugging might get interesting. ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can check how many args were passed by checking the length of `@_`

```
sub makeDeposit {
    my $amount;
    if (@_) {
       ($amount) = @_;
    } else {
        system("cls");
        print "How much money do you want to deposit?: ";
        chomp($amount = <STDIN>);
    }

    $self->insufficientFunds(0);
    $self->balance($self->balance() + $amount);
    $self->performBalanceInquiry();
}
```

Often, as is the case here, it's simpler to check if the parameter is defined.

```
sub makeDeposit {
    my ($amount) = @_;
    if (!defined($amount)) {
        system("cls");
        print "How much money do you want to deposit?: ";
        chomp($amount = <STDIN>);
    }

    $self->insufficientFunds(0);
    $self->balance($self->balance() + $amount);
    $self->performBalanceInquiry();
}
```

Note that your example shows an inappropriate division of concerns. Different modules should be handling IO and the account.

Comment: "Note that your example shows an inappropriate division of concerns. Different modules should be handling IO and the account."... as evidenced by the need to duplicate the actual deposit code.

Comment: @Oesor, That's a separate issue, since making `makeDeposit()` call `makeDeposit(Int)` would remove the duplication without addressing what I pointed out.